# spring security java config remember me by java config

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

how to configurate remember me by java configuration.
By xml its look like

```
<http use-expressions="true">

        <logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />

        <remember-me key="uniqueAndSecret"/>
    </http>
```

in Java class have next configurations , but remember me does not work,but with xml was working..

```
http.formLogin()
                .loginPage("/error?message=you have not permiss.")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                .successHandler(getAuthenticationSuccess())
                .failureUrl("/error?message=wrong password or login")
                .usernameParameter("j_username")
                .passwordParameter("j_password")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .and()
                .rememberMe();

        http.logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .permitAll();
```

Comment: Could you give some more detail on the problem you are having and what you have tried so far when trying to resolve it?

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-remember-me-example/

Answer (score 2):

Use the `.key()` method

```
http.formLogin()
    .loginPage("/error?message=you have not permiss.")
    ...
    .and()
    .rememberMe()
    .key("uniqueAndSecret");
```